# Is there any way to create reciprocal related entries?

Tags: entries, relations

I'm working on a sign language dictionary project. Each individual sign (or word) is an entry.

I want to be able to have an area that shows words that are similar to the word that is being currently viewed. I'm looking for a way to create reciprocal relationships between word entries to show these similar words.

For example, I want to say that word A is related to word B. Then I'd like for word B to also be automatically related to word A without having to go into word B and manually create the relationship.

Is there any way to make this kind of reciprocal relationship in craft? Thanks for any ideas.

Comment: Something like this what you're looking for? https://github.com/iainurquhart/craft_introvert

Comment: This is close, but not exactly what I am hoping for. However, this may be a possible work around. I've also looked at this plugin: [Reverse Relations](https://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/reverse-relations). At the most basic level, what I'm looking for is that if I create a relationship between A & B, then an inverse relationship between B & A is also automatically generated.

Comment: Should be doable programmatically just from listening to the `onSaveEntry` event then analyzing the fields, etc.

Comment: You're suggesting developing a custom plugin, right?

Comment: Yeah, I can't think of anyway to pull it off natively.